# Extracting Digits from Year and Concatenation

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have variable x = 2001. I want to produce a string that looks like this:
"TEST0106.xls". The 01 in that string is the last two digits of 2001, and the 06 is the last two digits of 2006 (x+5).

My current code is this:

```
%let x = 2001;
%let sub1 = %sysfunc(mod(&x, 100));
%let sub2 = %sysfunc(mod(&x+5, 100));
%let test = TEST&sub1&sub2.xls;
%put &test;
```

However, this just gives me "TEST16xls" since the 0 disappears in the modulus division and I'm not sure why the period isn't there. I believe I'll have to do some approach where I convert the numbers into characters and do a sub-string. How would I go about this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you don't need to use modulo arithmetic to do a substring in macro variable land, everything is text, so just use `%substr`.

Second, you can give an optional argument to `%sysfunc` telling it how to format the result; use the `z2` format to tell it what you want.  I think leaving the modulo is convenient here simply because it does give you that option.  Otherwise you can use `%sysfunc(putn(` if you want to not use modulo.

Third, you need another `.` since the first one ends the macro variable (technically macro variables are `&` to `.` inclusive unless they hit another character that is invalid for macro variable names first).

```
%let x = 2001;
%let sub1 = %substr(&x,3,2);
%let sub2 = %sysfunc(mod(&x+5, 100),z2.);
%let test = TEST&sub1.&sub2..xls;
%put &test;
```

or

```
%let sub2 = %sysfunc(putn(&sub1.+5,z2.));
```